# build a sum from a muliplication

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I want to build a sum out of two columns which are factors of a multiplication. Please see the sample data:

```
+------------+-------------+
| Amount     | Rate        |
+------------+-------------+
|  8         |         4.1 |
|  3         |         2.5 |
|  7         |         5.3 |
+------------+-------------+
```

so I have this table and I am struggling with the total amount of these results of the multiplication. I could have built a third column and calculate (8*4.1)+(3*2.5)+(7*5.3)

but instead I want to do it directly out of the two columns. So far I used

```
sum(amount) * sum(rate)
```

but it doesn't give me the right results. Can anyone please help me and tell me what the right formula is?

Thank you very much!

Comment: it should be `sum(amount*rate)`

Comment: You do realize that `(8*4.1)+(3*2.5)+(7*5.3)` is not the same as `(8 + 3 + 7) * (4.1 * 2.5 * 5.3)`, right?

Comment: It's not wrong, you did something wrong on your end. Based on that sample data, sum(amount*rate) will result in 77.4. Here's a demo: http://rextester.com/ZZGR90732

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `sum(amount) * sum(rate)` you are multiplying the values after they are summed. To sum the multiplied values you need to use `sum(amount * rate)`

Comment: Well I am looking for the result of 77.4 but sum(amount*rate) gives me 214.2. So it's wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that the values in that you posted are exactly like your data?

Comment: That's such a sample. But I am looking for the correct mathematical operation in order to apply the appropriate formula.

Comment: That code will give you 77.4 @not_ur_avg_cookie. `declare @table table (Amount int, Rate decimal(2,1))
insert into @table
values
(8,4.1),
(3,2.5),
(7,5.3)

select sum(Amount * Rate)
from @table`. I'm not sure how you are getting 214.2.: http://rextester.com/ZZGR90732

Comment: But sum(amount * rate) IS the appropriate formula. And using your sample data it DOES return 77.4. 214.20 is the original (and incorrect) formula you posted originally. Several people have already pointed out that it is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, you're right. For some reason I thought that sum(amount * rate)  was incorrect but it gives me the right results de facto.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this ...

```
sum(amount*rate)
```